# is it possible to create a locate database for a network volume in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, afp, locate

I need to be able to quickly search through millions of files on a network volume and instead of searching directly I’d like to look up the info in a database.

Instead of “rolling my own” it seems reasonable to use `locate` or `mlocate` to build a database but I have not been able to get `locate` or `mlocate` to work on an AFP network attached volume (or SMB for that matter).

Does anyone have a suggestion? I changed the `locate.rc` file in all combinations that I could think of but I suspect that neither AFP ro SMB are acceptable for the FILESYSTEMS line.

```
FILESYSTEMS="hfs ufs afp"
```

I tried NFS buit I don’t have access to the server to be able to set it up to accept connections from a Mac (it seems to require that you set “insecure” as one of the options for the domain).

Comment: Have you considered using `mdfind` (I.e. Spotlight) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it -is- possible to make locate.updatedb index other filesystems, including network attached.
The catch is that the root of the filesystem (and the tree down to the content you want indexed) must be readable by user/group "nobody".

You were on the right track with /etc/locate.rc

Following this further, I found that /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb just uses find to build the index.
It loops through the entries in /etc/locate.rc FILESYSTEMS (on 10.6, at least, this defaults to just hfs if unset).

find's man page suggests using "sysctl vfs" to find out what's valid on your machine. 
In my case:

```
sysctl vfs|grep mounted
vfs.nfs has 1 mounted instance
vfs.hfs has 3 mounted instances
vfs.autofs has 3 mounted instances
vfs.afpfs has 4 mounted instances
```

Some quick testing to validate this:

```
prowler:~%% mount |grep Volumes/keen
afp_1I6KyU4igzg00Q0vsj4E2G0H-1.2f0004fb on /Volumes/keen (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by keen)
prowler:~%% touch /Volumes/keen/test-afpfs
prowler:~%% find /Volumes/keen/ -name test-afpfs -fstype afpfs
prowler:~%% find /Volumes/keen/test-afpfs -name test-afpfs -fstype afpfs
/Volumes/keen/test-afpfs
prowler:~%% find /Volumes/keen/test-afpfs -name test-afpfs -fstype hfs
prowler:~%%
```

For 10.6, at least, afpfs is correct for an AFP mounted filesytem.

Now to the failure for afpfs.

When OSX (10.6) mounts the AFP volume 
(mounted via a login item or Finder -> Go -> connect to server - the traditional OSX mechanisms for AFP), it mounts it as readable only by user:

```
prowler:/Volumes/keen%% ls -ld /Volumes/keen
drwx------  6 keen  keen  264 Dec 13 12:45 /Volumes/keen/
```

and attempting to manually correct this fails:

```
prowler:/Volumes/keen%% sudo chmod a+rx /Volumes/keen
prowler:/Volumes/keen%% ls -ld /Volumes/keen
drwx------  6 keen  keen  264 Dec 13 12:52 /Volumes/keen/
```

I haven't found a workaround yet (I haven't tried autofs, since that method tends to be broken every OSX release...).

hfs (and presumably hfs+, etc) volumes that get mounted dont have this problem, nor do NFS volumes mounted via Disk Utility -> NFS Mounts (10.6).

```
prowler:~%% mount |grep nfs
murf:/backups on /Users/keen/backups (nfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
prowler:~%% ls -ld /Users/keen/backups
drwxrwxrwx  33 root  wheel  2048 Dec 13 03:05 /Users/keen/backups/
```

I discovered this when trying to test locate indexing only the afp mount:

```
prowler:/Volumes/keen%% grep FILESYSTE /etc/locate.rc 
FILESYSTEMS="afpfs"

prowler:/Volumes/keen%% sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedbshell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
find: .: Permission denied
```

Running with $PWD outside of the afp mount didn't have that error:

```
prowler:~%% sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
prowler:~%%
```

but also didn't have any results:

```
prowler:~%% locate test-afpfs
prowler:~%%
```

So the short answer as I've found it so far -  YES!  You can get locate to index network volumes on OSX.   NO, you can't index an afp network volume.

Comment: I have not had time to check this but reading it over it seems like the best solution yet so I am going to accept this. FWIW, in order to solve my issue I installed mlocate on the NAS server directly and then exposed the database on the shared volume, making it possible to grep the database directly.

Comment: ha, nice trick!

I went the run-as-root route for the moment....of course, with 6T to index between the nfs and afp mounts, that took a while!    another route would be to mount them twice - once nfs for locate, and once afp for osx-friendlyness, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're trying to search through millions of files you probably want to use something like grep via command line. You would access the share via /volumes/sharename (Provided that you've connected either via SMB or AFP).

```
#Print the files to screen:
grep -rI 'textstring' /Volumes/sharename/folder/

#capture the search in a file:
grep -rI 'textstring' /Volumes/sharename/folder/ > ~/desktop/searchResults.txt
```

*This can get quite large if you have a very loose search as it will capture all files that match.

If you're just trying to find a file then you can search like this

```
#display the results onscreen for a file ending in 'txt'
find /Volumes/sharename/folder -name '*txt'

#capture the results in a file on your desktop.
find /Volumes/sharename/folder -name '*txt' > ~/desktop/findResults.txt
```

*This can get quite large as well if you have a very loose search as it will capture all files that match.

You could use a database to store all of the files in but the database would be the size of the system in which they're stored and you would be replicating the functionality of the file system itself by doing this.

An alternative could be to search a local set of the files created using rsync. If there isn't an rsync daemon on the host machine you can still mine all of the files you have access to. Again you'll need as much space as the files you're mining.

Comment: find is NOT quick at all and is exactly the command I am trying to avoid... grep processes file contents, not the file names. It is possible to pipe a ls command into grep and search that way but you are still processing the file names at the speed of the network connection. The entire point of trying to get a locate database is to avoid the exact solution you're proposing - am I missing something?